# PATCH command for REST API on Katalon

Tags: rest, groovy, patch, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon 5.7.1(the last version until now) I was surprised when I created a Webservice Request object to access a REST API an check that the current command supported are - GET, POST, PUT and DELETE

I need to add PATCH command to the REST API.

First I try o follow the last answer in this [forum](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/8647/about-rest-api-patch-call) but I can import

```
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import okhttp3.Response
```

2nd I try to use the command curl in Katalon

```
curl -H Content-Type:text/xml -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN" --data @/path/to/JUnit_Report.xml https://host/api/v1/import/execution/junit?projectKey=XXX
```

The code in Katalon

```
ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder(
"curl", "-H", "Content-Type:text/xml", "-H", "\"Authorization: Bearer " + MY_TOKEN + "\"", "-X", "POST", "--data", 
"@/path/to/JUnit_Report.xml", 
"https://host/api/v1/import/execution/junit?projectKey=XXX"
);
pb2.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p2 = pb2.start();
```

I used windows 10 so I have to install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/) and to the path but I got this error

> - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/check_api_rest FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "curl -H
>     Content-Type:text/xml -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN"
>     --data @/path/to/JUnit_Report.xml https://host/api/v1/import/execution/junit?projectKey=XXX":
>     CreateProcess error=2, the system can find the file specified     at
>     java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)

Any idea??
thanks in advance